# Not able to send data to recyclerview

Tags: android, json, android-recyclerview, retrofit

I have a problem on how to display data i m getting from server using post request using retrofit. Here is my json data in which I want to display the "profile" in the recycler view. i m sending a string to server to get the data.

```
{
    "status": 200,
    "profile": {
        "firstName": "nelli",
        "lastName": "jhilmil",
        "gender": "Female",
        "addressLine": "Club",
        "city": "Delhi",
        "pincode": "560100",
        "phoneNumber": "2423232344",
        "userId": 50,
        "createdByAdmin": false
    }
}
```

This is the response json

```
public class ProfileResponse {

    @SerializedName("status")
    @Expose
    private Status status;

    @SerializedName("profile")
    @Expose
    private Profile profile;
    getters and setters...
```

Below is child model class.

```
 public class Profile {
    @PrimaryKey
    @SerializedName("userId")
    @Expose
    private Integer userId;
    @SerializedName("firstName")
    @ColumnInfo(name = "firstName")
    private String firstName;
    @SerializedName("surname")
    @Expose
    @ColumnInfo(name = "surname")
    private String surname;
    @SerializedName("gender")
    @Expose
    @ColumnInfo(name = "gender")
    private String gender;
    @SerializedName("phoneNumber")
    @Expose
    @ColumnInfo(name = "phoneNumber")
    private String phoneNumber;
    @SerializedName("addressLine")
    @Expose
    @ColumnInfo(name = "addressLine")
    private String addressLine1;
    @SerializedName("city")
    @Expose
    @ColumnInfo(name = "city")
    private String city;
    @SerializedName("pincode")
    @Expose
    @ColumnInfo(name = "pincode")
    private String pincode;
    @SerializedName("createbyAdmin")
    @Expose
    @ColumnInfo(name = "createbyAdmin")
    private Boolean createdByAdmin;
    getters and setters....
```

Below is the call wherein using post method sending a string to server to get the data

```
@POST("user/getProfile")
Call<ProfileResponse> getData(@Body JsonObject jsonObject);
```

Below is Adapter code where i have no idea what to send as a list to send as arraylist to send data to adapter

```
public class ProfileAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ProfileAdapter.ProfileViewHolder> {
private Context context;
private  List<ProfileResponse> profiles;

    public ProfileAdapter(Context context, List<ProfileResponse> profiles) {
        this.context = context;
        this.profiles = profiles;
    }


    @Override
    public ProfileViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
      LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
      View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.get_profile_items, parent, false);
      return new ProfileViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ProfileViewHolder holder, int position) {
```

This is my retrofit call to send and get data from server

```
     jsonObj.addProperty("role", String.valueOf(ADMIN));

            Call<ProfileResponse> profResponse = AppAuthClient.geVuAPIServices().getData(jsonObj);
            profResponse.enqueue(new Callback<ProfileResponse>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<ProfileResponse>call, retrofit2.Response<ProfileResponse>response) {
//                    mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    if(response.isSuccessful() && response.body() != null) {

                              ???????????
        
                        Toast.makeText(GetProfile.this, "success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    }
```

I am getting the data from server but not able to send the fetched data from server to recyclerview. Would highly appreciate any help, thank you.

Updated question

this is how i initialized adapter in my activity

```
  getData();
    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
}
```

Comment: You should call the API to fetch the data in an activity. In tjis activity define and initialize the adapter

Comment: I updated my question @Sarah i m able to fetch data from server on calling api and i even initialized adapter in same activity but i m clueless as to what i send in retrofit response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you have adapter (ProfileAdapter.class) to show multiple ProfileResponse objects in your RecyclerView but you have only one ProfileResponse in your call/request.
This may not be the best way to show user profile but if you really want, follow this

Add this method to ProfileAdapter.class

```
public void swapData(List<?> newItems) {
        if (newItems != null) {
            this.profiles = newItems;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
```

Replace your code from edited:

```
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));
adapter  = new ProfileAdapter(getApplicationContext(), new ArrayList<>()); //TODO create filed ProfileAdapter adapter
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

getData();
```

And swapData in onResponse method

```
@Override
    public void onResponse(Call<ProfileResponse>call, retrofit2.Response<ProfileResponse>response) {
//                    mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        if(response.isSuccessful() && response.body() != null) {

           //TODO adapter.swapDate(response.body / ProfileResponse) 

            Toast.makeText(GetProfile.this, "success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        }
    }
```

It would be better to create a special view for the user profile without RecyclerView and update it. If you want to show more profiles in the list feel free to comment below...

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'll mark your answer as accepted, though my problem hasn't solved. You are right i m passing a single object and not an arraylist.

Answer (score 0):

Where did you set the adapter to the recyclerview like this:

```
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

I think you forgot to set the adapter,if you do so then,
you said that you got the data from the server but not able to send to the recyclerview right!! then you can do this :

```
  // Get the response from response.body() and save it in whatever your //response is typed(like your POJO class profileResponse)
```

//after that you can add this profileResponse into arrayList

```
    ArrayList<profileResponse> profileResponseList = new ArrayList();


if(response.isSuccessful() && response.body() != null) {

 profileResponse = response.body();
 
    profileResponseList.add(profileResponse);

                    Toast.makeText(GetProfile.this, "success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
               }
```

then add the end you can notify adapter to reflect that data onto recyclerview

```
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

simple and handle this data into adapter class